# What library of javascript should i use for data Visualization

Tags: library, javascript

I want to make Star topology graph, which have the source and the target node from a json file

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/gallery

Answer (score 1):

By far the most popular JS data visualization library is [D3Js](https://d3js.org/) (and it's free :-)

Take a look at [the gallery](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/gallery).

The S.O question ["D3 How do I create a Star Layout for a force directed map?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23851349/d3-how-do-i-create-a-star-layout-for-a-force-directed-map) ought to interest you, and shows how to draw this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try [visjs](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/). I like it because  R has a nice package for visjs binding, but visjs'  maintenance status is unclear to me.

More requirements please: should it be interactive, mutable with the mouse, or have nice text labels, etc?